# How can I rebuild Rhythbox's XML directory?

Tags: rhythmbox

I store my podcasts on an external hard drive that just failed, but Rhythmbox still lists them as downloaded. How can I get rhythmbox to rebuild its directory of podcasts, but keep the URLs of the RSS feeds?